# Find definite integral between $ x^2$ , $ y = -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}, x = 0 $

Tags: integration

First. I find that $ x^2$ and $ y = -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}$ intersect at $x = 1$
So i integrate $ x^2$ from $ x = 0 $ to $ x = 1$
Plus a triangle created by $ y = -\frac{1}{2}x + \frac{3}{2}$ from $x = 1 $ to $x = 3$
I get 4/3
But the answer is 11/12
Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should integrate linear function also on interval $[0,1]$. And that is even not necesary. Just calculate the are of trapezoid with basis 3/2 and 1 and hight 1 and that is  $5/4$.

On the other hand $$\int _0^1 x^2dx= {1\over 3}$$

So the ansver is $${5\over 4} - {1\over 3} = {11\over 12}$$

Answer (score 1):

The computation that you should do is$$\int_0^1-\frac x2+\frac32-x^2\,\mathrm dx.$$It turns out that it s equal to $\frac{11}{12}$ indeed.